# Aggregate multiple collections based on student Id

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to aggregate 2 collections in MongoDB based on a student's ID. One collection consists of student personal information, another one consists of the students logs. The issue is that the data is in array which is why I think my aggregation is not working. Any help will be appreciated.

**student collection**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("(Object ID here"),
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "John",
            "id" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Sandy",
            "id" : 2
        }
    ]
}
```

**logs collection**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("(Object ID here"),
    "logs" : [ 
        {
            "studentId" : 1,
            "activity" : "11112,334,123"
        }, 
        {
            "studentId" : 2,
            "activity" : "11112,334,123"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
dbo.collection("student").aggregate([
    { "$lookup": {
        "localField": "data.id",
        "from": "logs",
        "foreignField": "logs.studentId",
        "as": "studentInfo"
    }
    }]).toArray(function(err, results) {
        console.log(results);
    });
```

Expected result:

```
studentinfo: {
    id: 1,
    name: "John",
    activity" : "11112,334,123"
}
```

Comment: What version of mongodb you are using? And what output do you want?

Comment: Any reason to store data like this? Usually each student would be it's own document

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I want to have a joined result with students logs along with personal information

Comment: @Bajal true but this is part of a bigger application where student does not have that much info currently

Comment: @HeelMega could you just paste expected output for given input ?

Comment: @mickl I posted the expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below aggregation with mongodb **3.6**

So basically your foreign field is an array you need to use [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#lookup-multiple-joins) with the pipeline to [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the foreign array inside the [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#lookup-multiple-joins) pipeline and to match the corresponding `ids`.

```
db.students.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "logs",
    "let": { "dataId": "$data.id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$unwind": "$logs" },
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$in": ["$logs.studentId", "$$dataId"] }}},
      { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$logs" }}
    ],
    "as": "students"
  }}
])
```

or use this to merge both the arrays

```
db.students.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "logs",
    "let": { "dataId": "$data.id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$unwind": "$logs" },
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$in": ["$logs.studentId", "$$dataId"] }}},
      { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$logs" }}
    ],
    "as": "students"
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "students": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$students",
        "in": {
          "studentId": "$$this.studentId",
          "activity": "$$this.activity",
          "name": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$data.name", { "$indexOfArray": ["$data.id", "$$this.studentId"] }]}
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "students": [
      {
        "activity": "11112,334,123",
        "name": "John",
        "studentId": 1
      },
      {
        "activity": "11112,334,123",
        "name": "Sandy",
        "studentId": 2
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Where is dataId in the first query coming from?

Comment: `dataId` is the variable we have taken in `let` expression. Which is your `localField`.